Is there any $\lambda >0$ that satisfy this requirement?
Let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times N}, v \in \mathbb{R}^{K \times 1}$ be some given matrices (actually, $v$ is a vector). We assume $A$ has full rank.
Denote our variable as $P$, $P\in \mathbb{R}^{N \times K}$.
We know that $\| APv \|_F$ is convex in $P$, and $\|P \|_F$ is convex in $P$, since both are affine functions combined with convex functions.
We want to know if there exists some $\lambda>0$ such that any of the following function:
$$ \| APv \|_F - \lambda \|P \|_F,~~\| APv \|_F^2 - \lambda \|P \|_F^2 $$
is convex is $P$?

Are A, P tall/square matrices?

Not in general. Take $N=K\ge2$, $m=1$, $A = v^T = (1,\dots,1)^T$. Then
$$
\|APv\|_F = \left| \sum_{i,j=1}^N P_{ij} \right|,
$$
which is zero on the subspace
$$
\{ P: \ \sum_{i,j=1}^N P_{ij} =0\},
$$
while $\|P\|_F$ is not identical zero there.
You can achieve a similar effect with choosing $A = I_N$.

In fact, on the subspace
$$
\{ P: \ Pv = 0\}
$$
the function is zero. And there is no $\lambda>0$ as desired. I would expect that such a $\lambda$ exists if and only if $m=K=N=1$.
